# How to add new form using envDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I am creating a Visual Studio Add-inn, i need to add new c# windows form using envDTE.
any one can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in an add-in that was created from a template, then you should have the application object that was passed in.  In your onExecute, you can do this to add a form:

```
string templateItem = ((Solution2)_applicationObject.Solution).GetProjectItemTemplate("Windows Form", "CSharp");
_applicationObject.Solution.Projects.Item(1).ProjectItems.AddFromTemplate(templateItem, "MyForm.cs");
```